# geth: how to deep freeze more segments?

Tags: go-ethereum

I keep seeing "Deep froze chain segment", and indeed the freezer directory does grow, but here's my disk layout:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vdc        590G  475G   86G  85% /var/lib/geth/data
/dev/vdd        472G  248G  200G  56% /var/lib/geth/data/geth/chaindata/ancient
```

In other words, the "ancient" dataset is just a half of the regular. Why is it so small? Is there any way to make geth freeze segments more aggressively? The active dataset is on expensive SSD, and I would rather keep it as small as it reasonably should be

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can lower `FullImmutabilityThreshold` in `...\params\network_params.go` and recompile

Do note:

1. This is likely to hurt your peer count
2. It won't have much benefit due to how Leveldb, Geth's database works(it doesn't reorg the DB after deletion of keys and leaves "garbage" around).